# Solution to phpMyAdmin login problem seems unsafe

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I had trouble logging into my myPhpAdmin web interface, so after finding numerous posts suggesting I added my un/pw to the config file like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; //mysql username here
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password'; //mysql password here
```

It surprisingly worked.  But...it seems ridiculous that I need to expose my un/pw in a config file just for this to work!  Is there a better solution?

(And yes I'm putting the same un/pw into the config file that is refused in the phpMyAdmin login window)

Comment: Crystal ball asks: is your password all-ASCII? Are you pulling it from a password manager? Maybe (but probably unlikely) you're hitting a charset conversion or accent normalisation issue when you're going through the login mask.

Comment: It's probably more secure this way than the way you are imagining it might work. If you want the user to enter the database password to login, then PHP will need some way to store these between requests. That means the password would be stored in the session store which is less secure than a single configuration file in a known location. In general it's common for web apps to be configured with database credentials of some form. The only real alternative is for the container orchestration (K8s, ECS,...) to manage it.

Comment: credentials are all ASCII, so not that.  My previous phpMyAdmin install did not need credentials in the config file...so thats odd.  Once authenticated the web server could keep credentials in session vars, so I don't think it's necessary to resend on each request.